# Splitting a list in OCaml

Tags: linked-list, ocaml

I am wondering whether there is an option for splitting a list in half (or in general at specified element).

To be precise I would like to do something like this:
Having a list (of integers for example):

```
let ml = [1;2;3;4;5]
```

I would like to make two lists out of it with lengths specified with an argument of first list.

It would look like something like this:

```
let msl1, msl2 = split_at_point ml 3
(* msl1 = [1;2;3], msl2=[4;5] *)
```

To be honest I don't really care if the splitting occurs at the specific point inclusively or not. All I care is it would be fast and memory saving (no copying would be great). And I know that best in terms of efficiency is something like O(n) where `n` the length of the first list (of the results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid copying the first half of the list. List are immutable, so the only way to get the new list is to copy elements from the original list.

The second half of the list doesn't require a copy, because the tail of a list is a list.

There's no built-in function for doing this (in the OCaml standard library anyway), so I'd suggest you write your own.

This seems very much like something that would come up a homework assignment, so I'll just say that the way to write most list functions in a functional language is to ask yourself how you could use a function that works for a smaller input (generally, the tail of the list) to calculate the value for your original input.

In your case you have something like this:

```
let rec split_at_point l n =
    if n = 0 then
        (* Answer is obvious *)
    else
        match l with
        | [] -> (* Answer is obvious *)
        | head :: tail ->
            (* Call split_at_point on the tail and
             * construct your answer
             *)
```